# Empty Mapped Type in Typescript

Tags: typescript, mapped-types

If I have a generic mapped type that maps keys to functions.

```
type SomeMappedType<T, R> = {
    [K in keyof T]: (...args: any[]) => R
}
```

This gets passed to my consuming function via an options type where it itself is optional.

```
type Options<T = any, R = any, P extends SomeMappedType<T, R> = SomeMappedType<T, R>> = {
    prop1?: P
}
```

I consume this value and return the output type. In the implementation, if `prop1` is undefined it is ignored from the output. However, my `Output` type returns a non-empty mapped type in this case.

```
const test2: {
    [x: string]: any;
}
```

My output type is as follows

```
type Output<T, R, P extends SomeMappedType<T, R>> = ResolveType<{ [K in keyof P]: ReturnType<P[K]> }>;
```

Is there a way for the default `SomeMappedType<T, R>` to express that it effectively contains no keys. I'm looking for the mapped type equivalent of an empty array `[]`

Here is a [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAShDOB7ANgNwgFXBAPBgfFALxQZQQAewEAdgCbxQAUAdGwIYBOA5vAFxR2NEAG0AugEpihAN4BfKAH5SUATKgiA0lACWNKAGsIIRADNSYgRi1iocgNwAoR6EhQAyogC2EALLswSDosSDwAGlhCEhlHKDiNbT1DYzMLAVYOHn5BYXEpIkIYRzlnV2gAeTBgHUQaeDxiHJAImEahZqgABXIqWgYPbz8AoJDcDBaogZ9-QIhg7HDIyZj4qDBORDAARkUBTuLS7ChygFdgMDOcWPjx67iYMLuunup6Rk9p4bnRxZh8R0mcCQaEwC3UWl0%20iMJnMnUssAgwBOnBoP06NkIcnwTkcphONAAxtValAkD4AGL4gkNEjtFptYQRbqUV79D5DWbzULjSKNdkzEYLHl-fBMTbEuoCSoS%20rjB6dfBSKVnC7AX5M2QHRwE2rwYBQah6gBMjTJEEphKY6nWmy2aigpkQiHS%20UIWyNAGY7HIJPYoAB6f1QADuiE4BkY7EYelZc21uv1hv1JDNFoJVp9fsDpIAFogTsg6FAAEbQITkLxVEBQLwBA1HeSOIA) of the problem.

Thanks for any help!

EDIT:

The solution from @spender does work for my original example, which was perhaps too simple. Here is an [updated example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-LuJ-rF5xeIJbZRsK7np7wj7A8cWxwEgaCYLenxivoRgmOYxy-HAwCpJwPi3scNiEAoABk7ieN4vgBEEIThJEODgu+JyojgtYDvgkymOkRHeG6rIQAAYvRB5zmQJC9lAJ4wEG-q8XO55JNiV5lhAXK3lWsBbOJ6w3jyMn3o+DYpE2r6thS7YUV+XqKoJ-auhpLZkR2ek-oZ-74EwY5ZjQCoZvZOZVjAdzHHcVFSAI267vuyn5nWsgngA9CFbqeGAaoMqE2bAKGUIQOG2kfhcADkNpcGlDx6SGUECBlWWRtGzAqmlAAWEDIMgiBpXYTixQ58UsusiWuuopiIIgMoquOi4AMz1TFcVQNQRrjq6SBsmxNChEw6hhVA5XsIw6TZEI1BVCIFACHpvx+rOw6jhOAgtWAiVqhI9i8Y1RqjQgwCLpNzEzXNC3hctq00OtgSSRoO1usapr7cIh3CguYCLgIIhQYlYiXQ1I1jcAg0kFNrH0fNUCLdkiCcAYjArY8CKSSeEPjqdrWUg8ZPHVDGiw5S8NyFdji3fFyMACzPdNmPyFd2PhfA5WIKkyBVHairkCymYgFAZ2jdM8iOEAA) that show 2 different optional props with different types that both contribute to the `Output`

Comment: Does defaulting `T` to `{}` instead of `any` work for you? https://tsplay.dev/WPRpKN

Comment: In my simplified example yes that works, but in my real code, it doesn't as there are other properties of the `Options` type that depend on T. I will try and update the playground example to be more realistic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mapping the `any` type results in a `{[x:string]:...}` mapped type, so your problem can be boiled down to this simplified example:

```js
type A = {
    foo: "woo"
}
type M<T> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] }
type MA = M<A>
//   ^? {foo: "woo";}
type MAny = M<any>
//   ^? {[x: string]: any;}
```

When there's no type to infer, your generic type `T` becomes `any`. Perhaps defaulting it to `{}` instead of `any` might be a way forward?

```js
type MEmpty = M<{}>
//   ^? {}
```

so...

```js
function someFunc<
    T = {}, 
    R = any, 
    P extends SomeMappedType<T, R> = SomeMappedType<T, R>>(
        options: Options<T, R, P>): Output<T, R, P> {
    //...
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I made an edit with a more complex example that demonstrates what I'm trying to do better. I added comments for each of the failing/passing test cases.